# Sequelize doesn't use field alias from model

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have model called `proxyPool` with next fields:

```
poolId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
        model: 'pool',
        key: 'id',
    },
    field: 'pool_id',
},
proxyId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
        model: 'proxy',
        key: 'id',
    },
    field: 'proxy_id',
},
```

It's a N:M table for two tables which have next associations:

```
proxy.associate = (models) => {
    proxy.belongsToMany(models.pool, {
        through: models.proxyPool,
        foreignKey: 'proxy_id',
    });
};
```

and

```
pool.associate = (models) => {
    pool.belongsToMany(models.proxy, {
        through: models.proxyPool,
        foreignKey: 'pool_id',
    });
};
```

When I call `proxyPool.findOrCreate({where: {proxyId, poolId}})` it says that column proxyPool.proxyId does not exist, but in raw SQL I see:

```
SELECT "id", "pool_id" AS "poolId", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "pool_id", "proxy_id" 
    FROM "portnoi"."proxy_pool" AS "proxyPool" 
    WHERE "proxyPool"."proxyId" = '3' AND "proxyPool"."pool_id" = '1' LIMIT 1;
```

Why does it use alias for `poolId = pool_id` but not use alias described in model for `proxyId = proxy_id`?

Comment: I'd check to see if you are using the exact same element in your select list (where you have `proxy_id`) and your where clause (where you have `proxyId`).

Comment: I assume if in my where clause I use `proxyId` then sequelize should take `field` key from model definition and generate SQL with `proxyPool.proxy_id` instead of `proxyPool.proxyId`

Comment: Most weird that if I change alias (suppose to `proxyIdd`) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a query like that?

```
proxyPool.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        proxyId: {
            [Op.eq]: proxyId,
        }, 
        ...
    }
})
```